# Operation .* not supported for operands of type cell (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, math, physics

Here is the code that gives the problem:

```
nVelCurve      =       length( velnum );    % number of assigned velocity curves
pixLocVC       =       vel_imloc(:,1)';     % column index for each assigned velocity curve
nVelPts        =       nan( 1,nVelCurve );  % number of points used from each chosen vel curve 
pix            =       [];                  % row index for TWTT from velmodels, stacked
vels           =       [];                  % velocity for each TWTT from velmodels, stacked

    for i=1:nVelCurve
        
        data      =      sprintf( 'Fit%g', velnum(i) );
        data      =      DataFits.(data); 
        data(:,1) =      data(:,1);  
        dataidx   =      find( [data(:,1).*pps] < Npix ) ; %this line gives the problem
        data      =      data(dataidx,:);  
        pix        =     [ pix; ceil(data(:,1).*pps) ];  
        nVelPts(i) =     length(data); 
        vels       =     [ vels; data(:,2) ]; 
        
    end
```

For explanation

: data is an n*2 cell array with decimal integers
: DataFits is a struct of cell arrays
: pps and Npix are decimal integers

Comment: What is the problem? Please copy-paste the full error message into your post, including the stack trace. Don’t rely on people being able to run your code, make it easy for us to answer your question by giving us everything we might need to answer.

Comment: Your code depends on `DataFits`, which looks to be a struct. `DataFits.(data)` seems to be a cell array. If so, you can’t use it in a numerical operation. Please show us what this variable contains, ideally by building a [mre].

Comment: Note also that `data(:,1) = data(:,1)` doesn’t do anything.

Comment: DataFits is a struct which contains fields. Each field is a cell array with n*2 dimensions. For more information, there is a matlab function 'twtt2depth.m' which you can find on the internet.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mre], and explain what the goal is of the indexing. We can’t fix code that we can’t run or if we don’t know what it’s supposed to do.

Comment: data(:,1).*pps is element-wise multiplication of the first column of 'data' (which is a cell array) with a scalar (in this case, 'pps'). That is causing the problem.

Comment: In return i will get the linear indices of 'data', according to the condition ('<Npix'). I need to rewrite the multiplication operator!

Comment: I am trying cellfun(), but it is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You Cris Luego for your effort!
I have rewritten the offending line as below:

```
   dataidx = find( [ cellfun(@(x) x*pps, data(:,1) ) ] < Npix) ;
```

Kind Regards!